# is it possible to make an Asp.net IRC client?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to build a web-based irc client with JQuery. I know I need to open a socket to the irc server. What I'm wondering is, is it possible to open a socket purely from server-side C# code? Or would the nature of a web application prevent this and I would have to write a service to run on the host machine?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Did you see the SO [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/)? It is written on asp.net.

Comment: In my experience the most annoying part is to keep an open request from the browser to receive notifications from the server without constant polling.

Comment: @Oded, yes I have already built a jquery chat that uses my own database. It's easy since I'm in control of the server, but IRC is a little different as it requires a constant socket connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to make a socket connection from server-side ASP.NET code. On the other hand, given that you'd presumably want a *persistent* connection to the IRC server (rather than a new one on every request), you may want to write a separate service anyway - you don't want ASP.NET recycling to kick in and wipe all your context, for example.

Your ASP.NET code could then talk to your service to find out what had happened since the last request for that user, etc.

Answer (score 2):

One simple approach would be to setup a singleton WCF service which acts as the bridge to IRC. jQuery AJAX calls against that service could then post messages that were input by the user, as well as retrieve messages sent by other users.

Answer (score 2):

I have implement the chat with ASP.Net by using the SingnalR for duplex communication.
What I really done consist on the following steps.

1) ChatHub.cs

I have write down all the logic to connect with the IRC server and connect to the channels, receive different messages and notification from the IRC server. I then send these notifications to my ChatHub client by calling the javascript call backs from the ChatHub.cs

2) Client.aspx

Simple HTML page and it is using jquery to register the callbacks from the ChatHub.cs

3) IRCDotNet.dll

I have used this library to communicate with the IRC Server.

Hope, It will help somebody. Here is the link to download the IRCDotNet.dll

http://ircdotnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/50639